# In Rails, how can I change the text before validation messages "Correct the following errors"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm not asking how to change the (per-field) validation messages themselves—which is easy and well-documented—but the text that appears before them.  In the version of Rails I'm currently dealing with, this is "Correct the following errors".  I would like to add the word "please", to make the tone a little less demanding.  I've been unable to find anything in the Rails guides or by searching.  How do I do this?

This current app is stuck at Rails 4.2.10 because of a gem not compatible with Rails 5.

And yes, I searched the codebase several times for the string (and parts of it) that is appearing above the error messages.

Comment: Please let's know your Rails version

Comment: This sounds more like something that is in your views and which is not part of the framework. For example for the scaffolded views Rails adds: `<h2><%= pluralize(post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>`. This is application code and has nothing to do with ActiveModel::Errors.

Comment: It could also be a flash message which again has nothing to with ActiveModel::Errors. The Rails framework does not set any flash messages by default so if its not set in the the controller this might be from a gem such as Responders or Devise.

Comment: Please share how you display errors at the moment. Do you use a gem or a plugin? Or self-written views? Or do you use the `error_messages_for` view helper that came with old versions of Rails? Did you grep your project for the string `Correct the following errors`?

Comment: @spickermann Ah I forgot about that old trainwreck. :D

Answer (score 0):

For example #1

```
  validates :name,
            presence: true,
            length: { maximum: 70 },
            format: { message: 'Please Correct the following errors' }
```

For example #2

```
   validate :custom_validation

   def custom_validation
     #validation stuffs
     errors.add(:base, 'Please Correct the following errors')
   end
```

Comment: Not sure this answers the question at all given *"I'm not asking how to change the (per-field) validation messages themselves..."* in the original post. This seems to have to do with the view representation

Answer (score 0):

This question is **not reasonable** one since Rails itself works like this.

```
lib/rails/generators/erb/scaffold/templates/_form.html.erb.tt:
  1  <%%= form_with(model: <%= model_resource_name %>, local: true) do |form| %>
  2    <%% if <%= singular_table_name %>.errors.any? %>
  3      <div id="error_explanation">
  4        <h2><%%= pluralize(<%= singular_table_name %>.errors.count, "error") %>
            prohibited this <%= singular_table_name %> from being saved:</h2>
```